# Python Selenium how to do windows handle

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I am trying to handle multiple windows, but still confusing about that thing, please find my codes:

The 'code' line works just fine if I just open that link, but when after jumping multiple windows, it loses the way

also if the window[-1] jumps to the previous window, I tried to [-1]/[0]/[1], but no luck, that loop print'1', so is the window[1]the current window?

Any help will be appreciated!

```
url = 'http://biz.finance.sina.com.cn/suggest/lookup_n.php?country=&q=%09175708' 
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="list"])[2]/label/a').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
windows = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="title tit06"]/a').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('发行信息').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
size = len(windows)
for x in range(size):
  if windows[x] != driver.current_window_handle:
    driver.switch_to.window(windows[x])
    print(driver.title,x)
driver.switch_to.window(windows[1])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//td[@class="bluecnt info"])[1]/a[2]').text
```

Comment: Did you try using multiple drivers?

Answer (score 0):

To not "loose the way" try create variable for each newly opened window:

```
url = 'http://biz.finance.sina.com.cn/suggest/lookup_n.php?country=&q=%09175708' 
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# define main window
main = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="list"])[2]/label/a').click()
# switch to new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# define first window 
first = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="title tit06"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('发行信息').click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# define second window 
second = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//td[@class="bluecnt info"])[1]/a[2]').text
```

Then you will be able to switch between all opened windows as

```
driver.switch_to.window(main)
driver.switch_to.window(first)
driver.switch_to.window(second)
```

P.S. Also there is no need to call `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` several times as once it called it set timeout for the whole script

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help!  I modified with`driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="list"])[2]/label/a').click()
windows = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
first = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="title tit06"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('发行信息').click()`, I can see the window is current window but somehow it cannot locate, I used your code, same problem occurs, but the window is not on the latest open one.